# Xamarin Android ValueAnimator.OfInt() not work

Tags: android, animation, xamarin

I've try to animate int value like this

```
            intAnim = ValueAnimator.OfInt(0, 100);
            intAnim.AddUpdateListener(this);
            intAnim.SetDuration(450);
            intAnim.Start();
```

And write it in console while updating

```
    public void OnAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("e.Animation.CurrentPlayTime " + animation.CurrentPlayTime + "/ " + animation.Duration);
        Console.WriteLine("e.Animation.AnimatedValue " + animation.AnimatedValue);
    }
```

The value does not update from start value it's always set to target value so message in console will be like

```
e.Animation.CurrentPlayTime 0/ 450
e.Animation.AnimatedValue 100
```

Does not sure what is wrong..

Comment: check "developer options" > "animator duration scale"

Comment: Check it on the device right?, It's off. I try set it to 1x but it's still does not work.

Comment: restart your app then

Comment: Oh, It's work now. Thank you so much :)